# Prove that if $f$ is a real continuous function such that $|f|\le 1$ then $|\int_{|z|=1} f(z)dz| \le 4$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've encountered the following problem in complex analysis:

Prove that if $f$ is a real continuous function such that $|f|\le 1$ then $|\int_{|z|=1} f(z)dz| \le 4$.

I've decomposed $f$ to it's real and imaginary parts and got that it's enough to prove that:

$(\int_0^{2\pi}cos(\theta)g(\theta)d\theta)^2 +(\int_0^{2\pi}sin(\theta)g(\theta)d\theta)^2 \le 16$

Where $g(\theta)=f(e^{i\theta})$.

But now I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Use the fact that there is a complex number $z_{0}=e^{it}$ such that $$z_{0}\int_{|z|=1}{f(z) \, dz}= |\int_{|z|=1}{f(z) \, dz}|$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the hint by  [TheOscillator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332449/prove-that-if-f-is-a-real-continuous-function-such-that-f-le-1-then-int#comment2707563_1332449):

> use the fact that there is a complex number $z_{0}=e^{it}$ such that $$z_{0}\int_{|z|=1}{f(z) \, dz}= \left|\int_{|z|=1}{f(z) \, dz}\right|$$

The advantage this gives is that we only have real part to worry about. Writing $z=e^{is}$, the real part of the left hand side becomes
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} -f(e^{is}) \sin(t+s)\,ds $$
Now the triangle inequality reduces this to the integration of $|\sin|$ over an interval of length $2\pi$. This integral is indeed $4$.

Comment: Why the triangle inequality? I would just slap absolute values on.

Comment: Some people call doing that [the triangle inequality for integrals](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality_for_Integrals). Because the integral is like a sum, and we're bounding the absolute value of a "sum" but a "sum" of absolute values.

Comment: OK, never saw that before, but it makes sense.